# My Dell 1950 iii can't enable Virtualization Technology (VT-x)

Tags: networking, dell-poweredge, xenserver

I have a Dell 1950 iii 
I have 2 x [Intel Xeon Processor L5420  2.50 GHz, 1333 MHz FSB cpu](http://ark.intel.com/products/33929/Intel-Xeon-Processor-L5420-12M-Cache-2_50-GHz-1333-MHz-FSB).

I have installed XenServer 7.0 on it.
And it will boot the XenServer fine.

But when I try to install a VM via XenCenter
I get the "HVM" error message.

After a little of googleing
I find that I need to enable Virtualization Technology in the bios.

So I reboot.
Then press **F2**.

Bios is version: 2.2.6

Then press
**CPU infomation** -> 
But the **Virtualization Technology** option is NOT there.

Do I need to upgrade the bios or ...?

Answer (score 3):

Under `CPU/PROCESSOR SETTINGS` you should be able to set `VIRTUALIZATION TECHNOLOGY` to enabled, as shown [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/bios-cpu-vt-setting-for-vmware/)

Comment: Yep, that's it. Can confirm, as I run about thirty of these suckas, still.